# Javascript regex (extract string)

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I always forget how to create simple regular expressions despite doing projects with more complex regexes...

I have the string:

```
var s = "qwehref=\"1232.css\"qwasd asd asdqq eehref=\"asd.css\""
```

I want to capture the text inside the href tags: `1232.css` and `asd.css`.

I've tried with this regex:

```
var re = /href="(.+\.css)"/g
```

but this is what I get (`re.exec(s)`):

```
'1232.css"qwasd asd asdqq eehref="asd.css'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
/href="([^"]+\.css)"/g
```

You don't want to match the closing quote as part of your file name. Or just use a non greedy match I guess...

```
/href="(.+?\.css)"/g
```

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer because you have less reputation points :)

Answer (score 5):

Greediness problem try

```
var re = /href="(.+?\.css)"/g
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33ljj)

The `?` after a quantifier changes the matching behaviour of that quantifier to **match as less as possible**